# Swift 5.3 Compiler Crash for TableView Getter

Tags: swift5, xcodebuild, xcode12

while doing xcodebuild, compiler is getting crashed at below first line where the tableView was declared.

> ```
> var tableView: UITableView? {
>     get {
>         var table: UIView? = superview
>         while !(table is UITableView) && table != nil {
>             table = table?.superview
>         }
>         return table as? UITableView
>     }
> }
> ```

Here is the stack trace for the compiler crash

```
2. Apple Swift version 5.3 (swiftlang-1200.0.28.1 clang-1200.0.30.1)
3.  While evaluating request ExecuteSILPipelineRequest(Run pipelines { EarlyModulePasses, HighLevel+EarlyLoopOpt, MidModulePasses+StackPromote, MidLevel, ClosureSpecialize, LowLevel, LateLoopOpt, SIL Debug Info Generator } on SIL for TestApp.TestApp)
4.  While running pass #835 SILFunctionTransform "SimplifyCFG" on SILFunction "@$s10TestApp31EditProfileAboutMeTableViewCellC05tableH0So07UITableH0CSgvg".
 for getter for tableView (at /Users/madhu/Downloads/Agent/_work/3/s/TestApp/MoreTab/Views/EditProfileAboutMeTableViewCell.swift:26:9)
0  swift                    0x0000000104b05a85 llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(llvm::raw_ostream&) + 37
1  swift                    0x0000000104b04a85 llvm::sys::RunSignalHandlers() + 85
2  swift                    0x0000000104b0603f SignalHandler(int) + 111
3  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff6b2f8d7d _sigtramp + 29
4  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x0000000106d58400 _sigtramp + 18446603343127508640
5  swift                    0x0000000100ef207a (anonymous namespace)::SimplifyCFG::simplifyBlocks() + 2458
6  swift                    0x0000000100eea847 (anonymous namespace)::SimplifyCFG::run() + 119
7  swift                    0x0000000100eea79a (anonymous namespace)::SimplifyCFGPass::run() + 890
8  swift                    0x0000000100e0e97b swift::SILPassManager::runFunctionPasses(unsigned int, unsigned int) + 4299
9  swift                    0x0000000100e0ad5a swift::SILPassManager::executePassPipelinePlan(swift::SILPassPipelinePlan const&) + 138
10 swift                    0x0000000100e24bfc swift::SimpleRequest<swift::ExecuteSILPipelineRequest, std::__1::tuple<> (swift::SILPipelineExecutionDescriptor), (swift::RequestFlags)1>::evaluateRequest(swift::ExecuteSILPipelineRequest const&, swift::Evaluator&) + 60
11 swift                    0x0000000100e13155 llvm::Expected<swift::ExecuteSILPipelineRequest::OutputType> swift::Evaluator::getResultUncached<swift::ExecuteSILPipelineRequest>(swift::ExecuteSILPipelineRequest const&) + 1045
12 swift                    0x0000000100e163b9 swift::runSILOptimizationPasses(swift::SILModule&) + 425
13 swift                    0x00000001007aa14e swift::CompilerInstance::performSILProcessing(swift::SILModule*) + 1358
14 swift                    0x000000010067ccd8 performCompileStepsPostSILGen(swift::CompilerInstance&, swift::CompilerInvocation const&, std::__1::unique_ptr<swift::SILModule, std::__1::default_delete<swift::SILModule> >, llvm::PointerUnion<swift::ModuleDecl*, swift::SourceFile*>, swift::PrimarySpecificPaths const&, int&, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 1288
15 swift                    0x000000010066cf98 swift::performFrontend(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 20712
16 swift                    0x00000001005ee277 main + 1255
17 libdyld.dylib            0x00007fff6b0ca851 start + 1
18 libdyld.dylib            0x0000000000000161 start + 18446603338720172305
```

Answer (score 12):

I ran into the same issue with very similar code for finding a `UITableViewCell`. The fix for me was to use a temporary variable in the while loop like so:

```
var tableView: UITableView? {
    get {
        var table: UIView? = superview
        while !(table is UITableView) && table != nil {
            let newSuperview = table?.superview
            table = newSuperview
        }
        return table as? UITableView
    }
}
```