# Command SwiftCompile failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, compiler-errors

I just upgraded to XCode 14 to test my app with iOS 16 since a bug has been noticed in the UI but it just stopped compiling (Downgrading to the previous XCode version 13.4 works again).

Here's the error stack trace when building the project.

```
4.  While evaluating request ExecuteSILPipelineRequest(Run pipelines { Mandatory Diagnostic Passes + Enabling Optimization Passes } on SIL for EightUsersUI)
5.  While running pass #0 SILModuleTransform "SILGenCleanup".
Stack dump without symbol names (ensure you have llvm-symbolizer in your PATH or set the environment var `LLVM_SYMBOLIZER_PATH` to point to it):
0  swift-frontend           0x0000000114b727f7 llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(llvm::raw_ostream&, int) + 39
1  swift-frontend           0x0000000114b71828 llvm::sys::RunSignalHandlers() + 248
2  swift-frontend           0x0000000114b72e10 SignalHandler(int) + 288
3  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007ff800d3adfd _sigtramp + 29
4  swift-frontend           0x000000010f98cc0e std::__1::__function::__func<swift::evaluator::PerRequestCache swift::evaluator::PerRequestCache::makeEmpty<swift::ProvideDefaultImplForRequest>()::'lambda'(void*), std::__1::allocator<swift::evaluator::PerRequestCache swift::evaluator::PerRequestCache::makeEmpty<swift::ProvideDefaultImplForRequest>()::'lambda'(void*)>, void (void*)>::operator()(void*&&) + 46
5  swift-frontend           0x000000011028f4b1 swift::CanonicalizeInstruction::canonicalize(swift::SILInstruction*) + 49
6  swift-frontend           0x00000001100fda24 (anonymous namespace)::SILGenCleanup::run() + 388
7  swift-frontend           0x000000011011ed35 swift::SILPassManager::executePassPipelinePlan(swift::SILPassPipelinePlan const&) + 3077
8  swift-frontend           0x000000011013b8fc swift::SimpleRequest<swift::ExecuteSILPipelineRequest, std::__1::tuple<> (swift::SILPipelineExecutionDescriptor), (swift::RequestFlags)1>::evaluateRequest(swift::ExecuteSILPipelineRequest const&, swift::Evaluator&) + 60
9  swift-frontend           0x0000000110127e69 llvm::Expected<swift::ExecuteSILPipelineRequest::OutputType> swift::Evaluator::getResultUncached<swift::ExecuteSILPipelineRequest>(swift::ExecuteSILPipelineRequest const&) + 537
10 swift-frontend           0x0000000110129f3b swift::runSILDiagnosticPasses(swift::SILModule&) + 187
11 swift-frontend           0x000000010f7ae551 swift::CompilerInstance::performSILProcessing(swift::SILModule*) + 65
12 swift-frontend           0x000000010f72f6c6 performCompileStepsPostSILGen(swift::CompilerInstance&, std::__1::unique_ptr<swift::SILModule, std::__1::default_delete<swift::SILModule> >, llvm::PointerUnion<swift::ModuleDecl*, swift::SourceFile*>, swift::PrimarySpecificPaths const&, int&, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 1110
13 swift-frontend           0x000000010f7319b5 swift::performFrontend(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 5701
14 swift-frontend           0x000000010f6c78ea swift::mainEntry(int, char const**) + 3082
15 dyld                     0x00000001258d852e start + 462
Command SwiftCompile failed with a nonzero exit code
```

I have tried to play with removing and adding Swift Package dependencies but with no luck, cleaned derived data, restarted Xcode and mac. I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Since we have very limited information compared with other similar questions like [another compiler error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63779031/swift-5-3-compiler-crash-for-tableview-getter). Your compiler died at the `SILModuleTransform` phase. I suggest you remove any suspicious module dependencies and see if your project compiles. BTW, check modules carefully, such as package/module name should not be the sample as any class/struct's name, etc.
[image]